# javascript for click drop down not working on Ipad

Tags: jquery, ipad, drop-down-menu, tablet

I have the following script that makes drop-downs in a navigation appear and disappear on click.

I'm creating this so that users can see the drop downs in my navigation when using an ipad.

The script works on all browsers on my desktop, but when i try it on an Ipad, the drop downs don't show.

Any idea why this is not working?

```
$("li.dropdown-control > a").click( function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    var nextSibling = $(this).next();
    nextSibling.toggleClass("dropped");  
    $('.dropped').not(nextSibling).removeClass('dropped');  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, iPad click event is not triggered the way it is on your desktop.

You'll want to watch for any of these events:

- touchstart
- touchmove
- touchend
- touchcance

With this code:

```
$('body').on('click touchstart','li.dropdown-control > a',function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    var nextSibling = $(this).next();
    nextSibling.toggleClass("dropped");  
    $('.dropped').not(nextSibling).removeClass('dropped'); 
 });
```

*This will work for both desktop & tablets.*

Comment: I tried this and it still works on desktop, but not the ipad for some reason

Comment: what if I only want it to work on a tablet? Would that make it easier?

Comment: doesn't make a difference. Are you sure your javascript is not cached?

Comment: yes, i just added an alert in the code too, and it appears when I click on the ipad. So Im wondering if the toggleclass is an issue?

Comment: Might be. Please debug & raise another issue on SO if you cannot figure it out. I guess this makes this issue solved right?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem before but i found a way around it.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#clickme').click(function() {
$('#me').slideToggle(function() {
$('.showhide').text(
  $(this).is(':visible') ? "Close" : "Open"
 );
 });
});
```

Then just edit it to suite your need :)
Hope it helps!